# Repeat Pop-Up Alert If Left Empty?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have created a pop-up alert using this code:

```
text=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Pop-Up Text" default answer "")')
```

However, I would like this prompt to run over again if the answer is left blank. I tried the following:

```
if [$text == ""]; then text=$(osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to text returned of (display dialog "Pop-Up Text" default answer "")'); fi
```

This works, however, if the pop-up is canceled or left blank the second time it doesn't reappear.

I just need the pop-up prompt to keep appearing if the answer is left blank or is canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a Bash script? If so, use a [while loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html) to present your prompt while `text` is `""`.